# What is Oracle/ArcSDE doing to my simple WKT Conversions?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have no way to explain the output of the following:

```
DECLARE
   splitGeom         sde.ST_Geometry;
   stas              CLOB;
 BEGIN
   SELECT sde.st_geomfromtext( 'POLYGON ((468221.1280508253 266651.4444917827, 468228.9861915416 266649.3489875917, 468227.9384394461 266641.75278489926, 468221.3899888492 266642.5385989709, 468221.1280508253 266651.4444917827))', 3071)
   INTO splitGeom FROM dual;

   SELECT sde.ST_AsText(splitGeom) INTO stas FROM Dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Split Geom is '|| TO_CHAR(stas));
END;

Split Geom is POLYGON  (( 468221.12810000 266651.44450000, 468221.39000000 266642.53860000, 468227.93840000 266641.75280000, 468228.98620000 266649.34900000, 468221.12810000 266651.44450000))468205.77370000 266629.13260000, 468218.02320000 266621.20040000, 468231.86460000 266608.11490000, 468247.40590000 266600.56050000, 468256.84900000 266609.81520000, 468275.92460000 266606.33490000, 468286.42020000 266607.87300000, 468293.94750000 266630.91490000, 468284.87680000 266637.23710000, 468281.98080000 266648.29150000, 468274.58700000 266650.42930000, 468260.34120000 266654.54830000, 468247.17220000 266653.34600000, 468244.73380000 266651.44650000, 468232.53850000 266644.37730000, 468228.46460000 266645.56750000, 468
```

That output is copied directly from TOAD. i did not truncate it. And even if i did how is there that many coordinates from the input i sent?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Might be a buffer overflow in the output function, and nothing to do with ST_GEOMETRY.